# Lorentz $\Lambda$ matrix problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

I have two systems of coordinates:
$$\{x^{\mu}\} = \{t, x, y, z\}$$

$$\{x^{\alpha'}\} = \{t', x', y', z'\} = \{t, x+y, x-y, z\}$$

And I have to find the Lorentz $\Lambda$ matrix of the transformation.

What I know is

$$x^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\alpha'} x^{\alpha'}$$

and hence

$$\Lambda^{\mu}_{\alpha'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha'}}$$

So it should be easy but then there is something I cannot understand: how to compute, for example ?

$$\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^{1'}} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial (x+y)}$$

The result should be anyway

$$
\Lambda = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And I don't understand why, since I did the calculation and instead of all the $1/2$ terms, I get $1$.

Comment: Why not just solve the matrix equation?

Comment: It may be easier to first compute $\Lambda^{-1}$, and then invert the matrix. Or use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

To compute $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}$ one needs
$$
x=\frac{1}{2}(x'+y')
$$
so that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}=\frac{1}{2}$.  Likewise one need $y$ as a function of $x'$ and $y'$ to compute $\partial y/\partial y'$.

Note that the transformation $x\to x'=x+y, y\to y'=x-y$ is not a Lorentz transformation so cannot be expected to yield a metric-preserving transformation. The simplest way to see this is to note that the determinant of the suggested transformation is given by 
$$
\hbox{Det}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1  \\  1 & -1\end{array}\right)=-2
$$
so this transformation does not preserve the space-only length of a vector.

The correct transformation to the new coordinate system should be 
$$
x\to x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)\, ,\qquad y\to y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)
$$
and corresponds to a rotation in the $xy$ plane by $\pi/4$ and a reflection.

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @KyleKanos  I fixed it.

Comment: Eh, not sure I'd agree that it should be migrated to MSE, but you've got enough rep to make the vote if you want to start the petition to do so.

Comment: Right... In the end I don't think is so wise either so I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

As Henry Turing said, your answer is correct.  However, your $\Lambda$ should not be called a Lorentz matrix. For a matrix to belong to the Lorentz group it's determinant must be 1, and it must leave the metric diag(-1,1,1,1) invariant. The matrix you called $\Lambda$ does neither.
$$
det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=-1/2
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Your matrix $\Lambda$ is part of the larger group GL(4).

Comment: "As Henry Turing said..." you do realize that Henry Turing also *asked* the question, no?

Comment: Nope, I didn't notice that Henry was playing both roles! But that's good he figured out the answer to his own question and told us about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.

Te matrix you found is actually the inverse matrix of the transformation, hence when you find your $\Lambda$ you have to invert it, et voilà: the result appears.